# Type annotation in a "lifting" wrapper

Tags: python

I'm playing around with different ways of wrapping functions to deal with `None` values, basically to eliminate some special cases in an algorithm. There isn't much to it, if a function gets `None` as a parameter, I want it to return `None`, and otherwise, it should work as if it didn't know about `None` at all. Implementing this as a function wrapper isn't hard either, but adding type annotations is a bit cumbersome the way I am doing it, and I was wondering if there is a smarter way.

So, I have some type-annotation variables

```py
from typing import (
    TypeVar,
    Callable as Fn,
    Optional as Opt,
    Any,
    overload
)

_T1 = TypeVar('_T1')
_T2 = TypeVar('_T2')
_T3 = TypeVar('_T3')
_T4 = TypeVar('_T4')
_R = TypeVar('_R')
```

(`Optional` and `Callable` got shorter names because I have to write rather long expressions)

I want a function `lift` that takes any function `f : T1 x T2 x ... x Tn -> Opt[R]` and lift the input type to `f': Opt[T1] x Opt[T2] x ... x Opt[Tn] -> Opt[R]` and I can implement it like this

```py
from functools import wraps

def lift(f: Fn[..., Opt[_R]]) -> Fn[..., Opt[_R]]:
    """Lift a generic function."""
    @wraps(f)
    def w(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Opt[_R]:
        if None in args or None in kwargs.values():
            return None
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return w
```

but doing this I throw away all type information about the wrapped function. The `...` becomes an unknown sequence of `Any`.

I've solved it with overloading

```py
@overload
def lift(f: Fn[[_T1], Opt[_R]]) -> Fn[[Opt[_T1]], Opt[_R]]:
    """Lift function f."""
    ...


@overload
def lift(f: Fn[[_T1, _T2], Opt[_R]]) -> Fn[[Opt[_T1], Opt[_T2]], Opt[_R]]:
    """Lift function f."""
    ...


@overload
def lift(f: Fn[[_T1, _T2, _T3], Opt[_R]]) \
        -> Fn[[Opt[_T1], Opt[_T2], Opt[_T3]], Opt[_R]]:
    """Lift function f."""
    ...


@overload
def lift(f: Fn[[_T1, _T2, _T3, _T4], Opt[_R]]) \
        -> Fn[[Opt[_T1], Opt[_T2], Opt[_T3], Opt[_T4]], Opt[_R]]:
    """Lift function f."""
    ...
```

but, as I said, it is a bit cumbersome, especially if I want to handle more arguments.

I don't think there is any way to modify `ParamSpec` variables, other than through `Concatenate` so I don't think it is possible to do anything there, but is there any other way?